# С чего начать хакинг ? Взлом соц сетей и тд?

Tags: взлом

Всем привет. Я совсем недавно начал увлекаться программированием знаю несколько языков программирования и у меня возник вопрос, какими языками программирования нужно владеть что бы взламать соц сети или что то иное . Ну в общем я хотел заняться хакингом, но с чего начать и что учить? И возможно ли это все самому выучить их и за какой срок? Анонимно

Comment: С прочтения OWASP-10. И чтобы взломать - владеть языками не обязательно. Важно - мышление. Нестандартное мышление!

Comment: Интересно, а `недавно` это насколько недавно и какие языки знаете? :)

Comment: @gil9red вангую - пхп. Его знают все мамкины хакиры

Comment: _Знаю несколько языков программирования_  вызывает сомнение если вы в таком случае до сих пор не знаете о том, что можно делать с этим инструментарием, не изучили сильные и слабые стороны и не знаете куда двигаться дальше.

Answer (score 8):

Надо начать с изучения Уголовного Кодекса, ибо как говорил Остап Бендер: *надо чтить уголовный кодекс*

[Статья 272, УК РФ](http://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_10699/5c337673c261a026c476d578035ce68a0ae86da0/):

> Неправомерный доступ к охраняемой законом компьютерной информации, если это деяние повлекло уничтожение, блокирование, модификацию либо копирование компьютерной информации, -
>   наказывается штрафом в размере до двухсот тысяч рублей или в размере заработной платы или иного дохода осужденного за период до восемнадцати месяцев, либо исправительными работами на срок до одного года, либо ограничением свободы на срок до двух лет, либо принудительными работами на срок до двух лет, либо лишением свободы на тот же срок.